# JavaScript switch divs by class list add,remove / toggle? how I can write better code?

Tags: javascript, class, dom, toggle

I am a beginning programmer and I would like to ask how can I improve this code? I know it's bad because there are a lot of repetitions and I would like to know how I can make it effective?

Thank you for any advice :)

```
 const simple = document.querySelector(".simple");
const speedy = document.querySelector(".speedy");
const easy = document.querySelector(".easy");

const illustration1Img = document.querySelector(".illustration-1-img");
const illustration2Img = document.querySelector(".illustration-2-img");
const illustration3Img = document.querySelector(".illustration-3-img");

const illustration1 = document.querySelector(".illustration-1");
const illustration2 = document.querySelector(".illustration-2");
const illustration3 = document.querySelector(".illustration-3");


simple.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    illustration1Img.classList.remove("hidden");
    illustration2Img.classList.add("hidden");
    illustration3Img.classList.add("hidden");

    illustration1.classList.remove("hidden");
    illustration2.classList.add("hidden");
    illustration3.classList.add("hidden");
});

speedy.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    illustration1Img.classList.add("hidden");
    illustration2Img.classList.remove("hidden");
    illustration3Img.classList.add("hidden");

    illustration1.classList.add("hidden");
    illustration2.classList.remove("hidden");
    illustration3.classList.add("hidden");
});

easy.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    illustration1Img.classList.add("hidden");
    illustration2Img.classList.add("hidden");
    illustration3Img.classList.remove("hidden");

    illustration1.classList.add("hidden");
    illustration2.classList.add("hidden");
    illustration3.classList.remove("hidden");
});
```

Comment: Have you tagged jQuery because you are looking for a jquery answer or?

Comment: Don't mean to interrupt your learning process, but is this kind of question allowed on StackOverflow? The "ask question" guideline says "The community is here to help you with **specific** coding, algorithm, or language problems.
**Avoid asking opinion-based** questions."

Comment: This is not a question for a specific problem? I wonder how I can improve it because this code is bad, I've seen countless questions of this kind on stackoverflow. Maybe not exactly that, to mislead, I want to hear someone's opinion, but I often see such topics here

Comment: If you accept jquery you can do it like, https://jsfiddle.net/6zdnhs2c/ . But it could be improved even more if you added the "numbers" to your click event.s

Comment: showing JS only is insufficient, it all depends on how the HTML code is articulated

Comment: carsten's suggestion is fine, but it's less readable. Sometimes it's ok to be redundant, it makes the code cleaner. Also it depends on the architecture of your project and its scope. Remember the saying YAGNIT (see wiki).
but with JQuery you could just call $('.simple, .speedy .easy'). each(function(){...}) And concentrate the work there, it would remove 2/3 of your code for the same result. and still be easy to read. Also use id instead of class if the behaviour is specific to one element.

Comment: @Sheed `('.simple, .speedy .easy')` is also valid in 'simple' JS too

Comment: @MisterJojo I mean, those are alright, but ".illustration-1-img", ".illustration-2-img" aren't very "class-like" to me

Comment: @Sheed it doesn't need to have classes for those elements, but anyways I won't post anything more here until PO adds the HTML part of his question